# Filter function that excludes values in column

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements, subset

I am trying to filter a column in a dataframe by only selecting values that are less than 5001 and then anything that is equal to 6000 and onwards

this is what i have but it is not working and unsure why

```
METable <- subset(outputdata, outputdata$Store.No < 5001 | outputdata$Store.No > 5999)
```

I used the above code with reference from answers below but for some odd reason it still isnt working for me. So the outputdata dataframe in the Store.No column I only have the store 5035...meaning nothing should show in the METable df but it still does...is there anything simple im missing out here

Comment: A number cannot be less than 5001 and greater than 5999. Replace with the and operator with the or operator: `|`

Comment: You should use the OR operator " | " , not the AND operator "&". Aditionally, if the values are numbers, uou should use them without quotes (5001), not ("5001").

Comment: @LMc I have updated my question with the new line of code and still getting the issue

Comment: @GuedesBF  I have updated my question with the new line of code and still getting the issue

Comment: Are you sure the column `Store.No` is numeric? Try `as.numeric(outputdata$Store.No) < 5001 | ...` on both sides of the `|`. Please post some of your data using `dput(head(outputdata))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying two conditions that can't possibly match. You are telling that Store.No has to be inferior to 5001 and at the same time superior to 5999. If you want everything less than 5001 and everything superior to 6000 you have to do this:

```
METable <- subset(outputdata, outputdata < 5001 | outputdata > 5999)
```

Also take into attention that you should be comparing numbers (without the "") as this might have an unexpected behavior, for example:

```
"2" > "11"  - Returns True
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense as @GuedesBF mentioned. You should not quote numbers for this since you don't want character behavior, though it may work in some cases.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right, although the comparison might work in some cases, it will definitely fail, and it is not the expected behavior. I've edited my answer to also accommodate this situation.